# pdftk crashes with large document

Tags: pdftk

I use `pdftk` '`dump_data`' function to find the bookmark pages in a large pdf. Sometimes, it returns an error.

```
pdftk main.pdf dump_data
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   main.pdf
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

The file `main.pdf` is produced with `pdflatex`. Whether it crashes or not seems to be dependent on the length of the document. If I take a chapter out of the .tex and recompile, then pdftk works fine. Which chapter I take out doesn't seem to matter. The full document is 173 pages.

**Update**
I am now not sure that it is related to its length. The document is 224 pages now, and can run sometimes on pdftk, but often not. The file is about 30mb. When I run any pdftk function, eg.

```
pdftk main.pdf cat output ../out1.pdf verbose
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
    main.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Comment: Use `verbose` at the end of your command to see where it might be failing.

Comment: Tried that - same error.

Comment: How big is a chapter?

Comment: Hard to imagine 20 pages would make it crash, unless the .`pdf` is large in `MB` ... I'm not sure what environment you're running it in.

Comment: 50mb or so. Ubuntu 12LTS.